# Implementing interactive confirmation in picocli

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

In a CLI app built using picocli, what is the most appropriate way to implement an interactive confirmation?

The scenario is, when a certain command is run, I need to get a confirmation from the user to do a certain task. I used the `interactive option` mentioned in the picocli documentation but it's not working as expected.

```
@CommandLine.Option(names = {"-c", "--copy-contract"},
            description = "Do you want to copy the contract in to the project?", interactive = true, arity = "1")
boolean isCopy;
```

The above option doesn't seem to trigger a user input when the command is run.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you invoking the command? Are you specifying the `-c` option on the command line? (That’s necessary to trigger the prompt.) I see the interactive prompt when I invoke the command with `-c`. What do you see?

Comment: I actually don't invoke it using the `-c`. I just run the command without the option and expected the prompt.

Comment: By spec, it is the occurrence of the `-c` option on the command line that triggers the interactive prompt. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Maybe the documentation (https://picocli.info/#_interactive_password_options) can be improved. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 7):

The `@Option(names = "-c", interactive = true)` attribute will cause picocli to prompt the user if (and only if) the `-c` option is specified.

If the application also needs to prompt the user when the `-c` option is not specified, it currently needs to be done in the application code.

As of picocli 4.3.2, this can be accomplished as follows:

```java
class MyApp implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = {"-c", "--copy-contract"},
            description = "Do you want to copy the contract in to the project?",
            interactive = true, arity = "1")
    Boolean isCopy;

    public void run() {
        if (isCopy == null) {
            String s = System.console().readLine("Copy the contract? y/n: ");
            isCopy = Boolean.valueOf(s) || "y".equalsIgnoreCase(s);
        }
        System.out.printf("isCopy=%s%n", isCopy);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args);
    }
}
```

(There is a [feature request](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/882) to include this in picocli in a future release.)

Comment: Hi, is `System.console().readLine()` the method of choice also when using picocli with jline? I thought there is a way to get the reader by commandSpec.commandLine()..., but I don't find it anymore.

Comment: @MayraDelgado JLine3 has its own `LineReader` class that should be used when combining picocli with JLine3. The [picocli-shell-jline3 Example](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-shell-jline3) shows how to create a `LineReader` in the `main` method. Notice how the `LineReader` is passed to the `CliCommands` application class.